# Include output from R markdown code chunks in report from command line

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R from the Linux command line because I do not wish to install R studio. I want to generate a pdf report that includes all of my code and the output from the code in a readable format as figures and LaTeX vectors.

I installed knitr and markdown using `install.packages('package')`

I imported using `library('library')`

I'm trying to render using `rmarkdown::render('path',pdf_document)`

My code chunks start with ``{r} yet when I generate the report and the pdf shows up it does not include any of the output from my code only the chunks.

Comment: Does your code end with ```?

Comment: Yes, it does otherwise it would not compile or generate anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to generate a report with results, the file extension on the readme file must be ".Rmd" rather than ".Rscript" or ".R"